# Easy way of implemetning layers in fragments?

Tags: android, fragment, layer

The Activity class had a method called `addContentView()` that could be used to easily add an additional view layer.  I'd like to create my own `BaseFragment` class that has a method similar to `addContentView()`.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this with minimal code?  It'd be nice if I could rely on `Fragment.getView()` always being a `NoSaveStateFrameLayout` since I could just use that, but I'm guessing this could possibly change with different implementations of Android.

I know I could just create a custom layout with a `FrameLayout` as the root but ideally I'd like the solution to be a re-usable framework, not specific to a specific `Fragment` class.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there isn't a clean, elegant way to do this.

What I have resorted to is this:

I created a utility method called wrapInFrame(View) that takes a view and wraps inside of a Frame layout and then returns the FrameLayout as a result (I stole the basic implementation from the support library source).  This method must be called from the onCreateView method in order to wrap your own custom view.

Once you have a FrameLayout at the root of your fragment's view hierarchy it becomes very easy to implement layering.